# Android Facebook SDK no class def found com.facebook.android.Facebook

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using a version of the Facebook SDK, I'm not sure which version as I was given the eclipse project and told to use it but it was given to me before SDK 3.0 was released, so most likely 2.0, in an Android app. The app's project has the SDK project listed as a required project to enable us to prompt for Facebook login within the app.

I've tried telling eclipse to export the project with or without the Facebook project but it makes no difference.

I have also tried running the app both with and without the official Facebook app installed.
Every time I try to initiate the login for Facebook, I get the message:

```
01-24 19:05:11.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12697): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook
```

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the build path on your java project to ensure the dependencies are there?

Comment: @gerrytan yes, that is what i meant by the projects being connected. Updating the question to be more clear now.

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251245/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-facebook-android-facebook

Comment: @gerrytan unfortunately I had tried that, and just to be certain I tried it again. Unless Eclipse isn't properly cleaning my project, that solution isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, one of my team-mates loaded up the project from Git, compiled it, and ran it with no changes and it works just fine. Clearly something is messed up with my setup somewhere whether it is with the Facebook SDK or Eclipse. I'm running Eclipse Juno, he is running Eclipse Indigo.

This turned out to be because I hadn't included the library project in the "Android" section of the project's properties.